# summarise() in R with NAs

Tags: r, tidyverse, na, summarize

I have a rather basic question, but I currently have a numeric variable in a data frame and I'd like to compute some summary statistics (say, the mean). Now, some of the values in the column are NAs, and naturally I won't use them, but I wouldn't want to use `na.omit()` either because I think that would drop some observations that have actual non-NA values in my column of interest but NA values in other columns.

Say my dataframe is called `df` and my column of interest `mass`. How could I compute the mean of the column without NAs?

Comment: Do you mean `mean(df$mass, na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: dplyr::summarise(df, mean_mass = mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE))

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I've tried this but was missplacing the ```na.rm = TRUE```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore NA values with the `na.rm` parameter:

```r
mean(df$mass, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but was missplacing the ```na.rm = TRUE```

Answer (score 1):

Use the na.rm argument

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c("", "s dasf"),    # Create example data
                   x2 = c("dafds", ""),
                   mass= c(1, 1, 2, NA))

mean(data[, "mass"], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but was missplacing the ```na.rm = TRUE```